# Can't get checkbox to behave with conditional statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

Thanks in advance for your help! I'm giving my users a way of viewing information that they have saved in my MySQL database. The problem is that my checkbox state is not loading according to what the user saved in the record.

```
    <% if !params[:newitem_id].blank? and @newitem.optimize != 1 %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="optimize" id="optimize">
    <% else %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="optimize" id="optimize" checked="true">
    <% end %>
```

My conditional statement starts by looking to to see if there is a newitem_id. This is a hidden field, and it just connects up all of the @newitem information with the view.

```
    <input name="newitem_id" type="hidden" value="<%= params[:newitemid] %>" />
```

When I use this in conditional statements elsewhere on the page, this works fine.

Next, my conditional statement looks into the record of @newitem to see whether optimize is a 1 or a 0. If @newitem.optimize is a 1, I want the checkbox checked. If not, I do not want it checked.

Unfortunately, the checkbox shows as checked even when the field is a 0.

**EDIT 1**

newitemlookup.html.erb is the view where the form with the checkbox lives. I've made some changes to it and have added the code from my controller. However, all of my checkboxes are checked, even if they are not supposed to be.

I also wanted to see what value the "@newitem.optimize" is returning, and it turns out that the 1 and the 0 in the database shows up in the view as "true" and "false" when I do <%= @newsavedmap.optimize %>. Could this be the problem?

newitemlookup_controller

```
    if params[:newitemid]
    @newitem = Newitem.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => params[:newitemid]})
```

newitemlookup.html.erb

```
    <% if params[:newitemid] and @newitem.optimize = false %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="optimize" id="optimize">
    <% else %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="optimize" id="optimize" checked="true">
    <% end %>
```

Comment: If you really have confirmed that `@newitem.optimize` is indeed `0` and you're seeing the checkbox checked, that must imply that `params[:newitem_id].blank?` must be `true`. Although I'd probably just check it for `nil` (unless you're really potentially expecting a "blank" non-nil value): `if params[:newitem_id] and @newitem.optimize != 1`

Comment: Thanks, mbratch. I've added the code for the hidden field to see if it actually should be blank. When I use your `if params[:newitem_id] and @newitem.optimize != 1` the checkbox is always checked, even when optimize is 0.

Comment: Like I said, the issue is the `params[:newitem_id]` value. If it's blank or nil, it won't matter what the value of `optimize` is, the checkbox will be checked. So `param[:newitem_id]` must be blank or nil in your case.

Comment: That's strange. In the sourcecode, `<input name="newitem_id" type="hidden" value="66" /> `. That's not nil or blank, right?

Comment: The problem isn't the `input` line but the `params` hash. The `params` hash is created and passed to the controller when the form is submitted. It's not a view variable. But you're checking it in your view. How do you know that `params[:newitem_id]` has been set according to your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and figured out how to add a checkbox that would look at the record and then return the result. Here's the code I used. This replaced the if/then statement.

```
    <%= check_box_tag 'optimize', '1', @newitem.optimize %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a form builder like f for instance:

```
 <%= check_box_tag 'optimize', '1', f.object.optimize %>
```